# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; Custom component

Tags: android

I have a complicated layout that caused me to create some custom components. The app requires that I need to add number of rooms, and in each, select number of adults and number of children per room. For each room, I need to allow multiple children per room, but for each child under 18 i need to know their age from a spinner.  I can add and remove rooms and add/remove children all day long. In each room I can add children and an age dropdown for each child and remove them. All that works no problem.  I get the error when I try to tap any of the age selector dropdowns. I suspect its something to do with context and activity, but not sure where.

The layout looks like[image] this:

I have a fragment controlling all of this, it controls the room stepper and adds/removes rooms.

### HotelSearchFragment

```
class SearchHotelsFragment : Fragment(), StepperView.StepperListener, CustomCalendarView.DayClickListener {


private var listener: OnSearchUpdateListener? = null
private lateinit var mViewModel: HotelRepositoryViewModel
private lateinit var mBinding: com.lixar.allegiant.databinding.FragmentSearchHotelsBinding

private lateinit var mRoomList: MutableList<HotelSearchRoomInput>
private lateinit var mRoomMgrList: MutableList<RoomGuestInputManager>

private var mRoomCount = 1;

interface OnSearchUpdateListener {
    fun onSearchUpdate()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mViewModel = activity?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(HotelRepositoryViewModel::class.java) }!!

}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_search_hotels, container, false)
    mBinding.handler = clickHandler
    mBinding.roomStepper.setCallback(this)
    setupInitialRoom()
    hideKeyboard()

    return mBinding.root
}

public fun getSearchCriteria(): HotelSearchInput {
    val mRoomData = HotelSearchInput.builder()
            .locationCode("")
            .from(mViewModel.fromDateLocal)
            .to(mViewModel.toDateLocal)
            .rooms(mRoomList)
            .build()

    return mRoomData
}

private fun setupInitialRoom() {
    val roomMgr = activity?.applicationContext?.let { RoomGuestInputManager(it) }
    roomMgr?.setActivity(activity!!)
    roomMgr?.setRoomNumber(mRoomCount)
    mBinding.roomExpansionZone.addView(roomMgr)
    mRoomMgrList = listOf(roomMgr!!).toMutableList()
    mRoomList = listOf(roomMgr.mRoom!!).toMutableList()
}

  override fun onDecrement(id: Int, count: Int) {
    when (id) {
        R.id.room_stepper -> {
            val lastRoomMgr = mRoomMgrList.get(mRoomCount-1)
            mBinding.roomExpansionZone.removeView(lastRoomMgr)
            mRoomMgrList.remove(lastRoomMgr)
            mRoomList.remove(lastRoomMgr.mRoom)
            mRoomCount--
            // once we have ONLY one room grow the left side to hider room numbers
            if (mRoomCount == 1) {
                val room = mRoomMgrList.get(0)
                room.adjustRoomOnRemoval()
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onIncrement(id: Int, count: Int) {
    when (id) {
        R.id.room_stepper -> {
            val roomMgr = activity?.applicationContext?.let { RoomGuestInputManager(it) }
            roomMgr?.setActivity(activity!!)
            mRoomCount++
            roomMgr?.setRoomNumber(mRoomCount)
            mBinding.roomExpansionZone.addView(roomMgr)
            mRoomList.add(roomMgr?.mRoom!!)
            mRoomMgrList.add(roomMgr)
            // once we have more than one room shrink the left side to allow for room numbers
            if (mRoomCount > 1) {
                val room = mRoomMgrList.get(0)
                room.adjustRoomOnAddition()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Within that fragment, I've incorporated a custom component, RoomGuestInputManager. It's job is to add "rooms", with an adult stepper and child stepper or remove them

### RoomGuestInputManager

```
class RoomGuestInputManager @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), StepperView.StepperListener {
val FULLSIZE_LEFT = 0.0f
val FULLSIZE_RIGHT = 0.5f
val SIZE_LEFT = 0.2f
val SIZE_RIGHT = 0.6f

val mRoom = HotelSearchRoomInput.builder()
        .adults(1)   // there must be at least one adult per room - sorry kids
        .childrenAges(listOf(0))
        .build()
private lateinit var mBinding: RoomSelectLayoutBinding
private var mNumChildren = 0
private var mNumChildMgrs = 0
private var mActivity: Activity? = null
private lateinit var mChildMgrList: MutableList<RoomChildManager>

init {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.room_select_layout, this, true)

    mBinding.adultStepper.setCallback(this)
    mBinding.childStepper.setCallback(this)
    mBinding.roomNumber.visibility = View.GONE

}

public fun setRoomNumber(room: Int) {
    val label = context.resources.getString(R.string.room_num)
    if (room == 1) {
        mBinding.roomNumber.visibility = View.GONE
        mBinding.guidelineleft.setGuidelinePercent(FULLSIZE_LEFT)
        mBinding.guidelineright.setGuidelinePercent(FULLSIZE_RIGHT)
    } else {
        mBinding.roomNumber.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mBinding.roomNumber.text = String.format(label, room)
        mBinding.guidelineleft.setGuidelinePercent(SIZE_LEFT)
        mBinding.guidelineright.setGuidelinePercent(SIZE_RIGHT)
    }
}

public fun setActivity(activity: Activity) {
    mActivity = activity
}

public fun adjustRoomOnAddition() {
    mBinding.roomNumber.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.guidelineleft.setGuidelinePercent(SIZE_LEFT)
    mBinding.guidelineright.setGuidelinePercent(SIZE_RIGHT)
}

public fun adjustRoomOnRemoval() {
    mBinding.roomNumber.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.guidelineleft.setGuidelinePercent(FULLSIZE_LEFT)
    mBinding.guidelineright.setGuidelinePercent(FULLSIZE_RIGHT)
}

public fun getGuestInfoThisRoom(): HotelSearchRoomInput {
    return mRoom
}

private fun setupNewChild() {
    val childMgr = RoomChildManager(mActivity?.applicationContext!!)
    mBinding.childExpansionZone.addView(childMgr)
    childMgr.setInitialChild(mNumChildren)
    if (mNumChildren == 1) {
        mChildMgrList = mutableListOf(childMgr)
    } else {
        mChildMgrList.add(childMgr)
    }
    mNumChildMgrs++
}

override fun onDecrement(id: Int, count: Int) {
    when (id) {
        R.id.adult_stepper -> {
            mRoom.adults().minus(1)
        }
        R.id.child_stepper -> {
            // depending on how many kids there are now, do we remove a layout or just make gone?
            if (mNumChildren == 1) {
                mBinding.childExpansionZone.removeAllViews()
                mChildMgrList.clear()
                mNumChildren = 0
            } else if (mNumChildren.rem(2) == 0) {
                // remove the secondary ageSelector
                val childMgr = mChildMgrList.get(mNumChildMgrs - 1)
                childMgr.removeChild()
                mNumChildren--
            } else {
                // remove the entire 2-selector layout
                val childMgr = mChildMgrList.get(mNumChildMgrs - 1)
                childMgr.removeChild()
                mChildMgrList.removeAt(mNumChildMgrs - 1)
                mBinding.childExpansionZone.removeView(childMgr)
                mNumChildMgrs--
                mNumChildren--
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onIncrement(id: Int, count: Int) {
    when (id) {
        R.id.adult_stepper -> {
            mRoom.adults().plus(1)
        }
        R.id.child_stepper -> {
            // depending on how many kids there are now, do we add a layout
            if (mNumChildren == 0) {
                mNumChildren = 1
                setupNewChild()
            } else if (mNumChildren.rem(2) == 0) {
                mNumChildren++
                setupNewChild()
            } else {

                // expose 2nd selector
                val childMgr = mChildMgrList.get(mNumChildMgrs - 1)
                mNumChildren++
                childMgr.addChild(mNumChildren)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That class controls a second custom component, RoomChildManager. It's job is to manage the age selectors for each room and make sure we have an age for each child. Its adds/removes the dropdown selectors in pairs to satisfy the design that when touched, give me the error in the title: 
        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

### RoomChildManager

```
class RoomChildManager @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), DropdownAgeSelectView.AgeSelectListener {

private lateinit var mBinding: ChildAgeselectLayoutBinding
init {

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.child_ageselect_layout, this, true)

    mBinding.child2Age.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.child2Num.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.child1Age.setCallback(this)
    mBinding.child2Age.setCallback(this)

}

public fun setInitialChild(num: Int) {
    mBinding.child1Num.text = String.format(context.resources.getString(R.string.child_age), num)
}

public fun addChild(num: Int) {
    mBinding.child2Age.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.child2Num.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.child2Num.text = String.format(context.resources.getString(R.string.child_age), num)
}

public fun removeChild() {
    mBinding.child2Age.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.child2Num.visibility = View.GONE
}

public fun getChildAges(): List<Int> {
    return listOf(mBinding.child1Age.getSelection(), mBinding.child2Age.getSelection())
}

override fun onAgeSelect(id: Int, age: Int) {
    when (id) {
        R.id.child1_age -> {
            // do something
        }
        R.id.child2_age -> {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas why touching any dropdown gives me the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew this was going to be a context issue, just couldn't tell from the error messages exactly where it was hitting.

It turns out, that the way to solve this issue lies in the way context was passed from the HotelSearchFragment to the RoomGuestInputManager.  I was assuming the context I could get a fragment was good enough.  Nope, apparently, they get confused, so I had to spell out exactly where the activity is.  In HotelSearchFragment, we set that as:

```
    val hotelActivity = context as HotelSelectActivity
```

then we can invoke RoomInputGuestManager like this:

```
    val roomMgr = RoomGuestInputManager(hotelActivity)
```

and also inside RoomInputGuestManager when we create the Child manager as

```
    val hotelActivity = context as HotelSelectActivity
    val childMgr = RoomChildManager(hotelActivity )
```

After that, everything works fine.